# how to decrypt in nodejs which is encrypted using JAVA

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, cryptojs

im trying to convert java lambda into javascript lamda. want to convert these encrypt and decrypt method which is written in java to node js or javascript.
I have tried to implement using crpto in node

keys are like this

```
private static String CIPHER_NAME = "AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING";
private static int CIPHER_KEY_LEN = 16; //128 bits
```

**encrypt method**

```
 private String encrypt(String key, String iv, String data) {
        try {
            if (key.length() <CIPHER_KEY_LEN) {
                int numPad = CIPHER_KEY_LEN - key.length();

                for(int i = 0; i < numPad; i++){
                    key += "0"; //0 pad to len 16 bytes
                }

            } else if (key.length() >CIPHER_KEY_LEN) {
                key = key.substring(0, CIPHER_KEY_LEN); //truncate to 16 bytes
            }


            IvParameterSpec initVector = new IvParameterSpec(iv.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"));
            SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "AES");

            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(CIPHER_NAME);
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, initVector);

            byte[] encryptedData = cipher.doFinal((data.getBytes()));

            String base64_EncryptedData = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(encryptedData);
            String base64_IV = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(iv.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"));

            return base64_EncryptedData + ":" + base64_IV;

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
```

**decrypt method**

```
private String decrypt(String key, String data) {
    try {
        if (key.length() < CIPHER_KEY_LEN) {
            int numPad = CIPHER_KEY_LEN - key.length();

            for(int i = 0; i < numPad; i++){
                key += "0"; //0 pad to len 16 bytes
            }

        } else if (key.length() > CIPHER_KEY_LEN) {
            key = key.substring(0, CIPHER_KEY_LEN); //truncate to 16 bytes
        }

        String[] parts = data.split(":");

        IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(Base64.getDecoder().decode(parts[1]));
        SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "AES");

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(CIPHER_NAME);
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, iv);

        byte[] decodedEncryptedData = Base64.getDecoder().decode(parts[0]);

        byte[] original = cipher.doFinal(decodedEncryptedData);

        return new String(original);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

I have used 
this is the solution i made but seems it not working cause i encrypted this using a java code and using node's javascript code to decrypt it.

```
function decrypt (messagebase64, keyBase64, ivBase64) {

    var key = Buffer.from(keyBase64, 'base64');
    var iv = Buffer.from(ivBase64, 'base64');

    var decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv(getAlgorithm(keyBase64), key, iv);
    decipher.setAutoPadding(false);
    decipher.update(messagebase64, 'base64');
    return decipher.final();
}
```

find the alogorithm i use this and adding padding if the key is not long enough but this give error that saying length is not enough.

```
function getAlgorithm(keyBase64) {

    if(keyBase64.length<CIPHER_KEY_LEN){
        var padding = CIPHER_KEY_LEN-keyBase64.length;
        for(var i=0;i<padding;i++){
            keyBase64+="0";
        }
    }else if(keyBase64.length>CIPHER_KEY_LEN){
        keyBase64 =keyBase64.substring(0, CIPHER_KEY_LEN)
    }

    var key = Buffer.from(keyBase64, 'base64');

    switch (key.length) {
        case 16:
            return 'aes-128-cbc';
        case 32:
            return 'aes-256-cbc';

    }

    throw new Error('Invalid key length: ' + key.length);
}
```

Comment: the question does not suggest that you have tried to implement a js solution yourself and a roadblock that you are hitting. To give you a direction however if you are new to node https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html is the documentation for cryptography in node.

Comment: added my implementation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after struggling for a while i have implemented encrypted method and decrypt method which will be identical to java.

**decrypt method**

```
function decrypt (messagebase64, keyBase64, ivBase64) {

    if(keyBase64.length<CIPHER_KEY_LEN){
        var padding = CIPHER_KEY_LEN-keyBase64.length;
        for(var i=0;i<padding;i++){
            keyBase64+="0";
        }
    }else if(keyBase64.length>CIPHER_KEY_LEN){
        keyBase64 =keyBase64.substring(0, CIPHER_KEY_LEN)
    }


    var key = Buffer.from(keyBase64, 'latin1');
    var iv = Buffer.from(ivBase64, 'base64');

    var encryptdata = new Buffer(messagebase64, 'base64');

    var decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-128-cbc', key, iv),
        decoded = decipher.update(encryptdata, 'base64', 'utf8');

    decoded += decipher.final('utf8');


    return decoded

}
```

**encrypt method**

```
function encrypt(plainText, keyBase64, ivBase64) {

    if(keyBase64.length<CIPHER_KEY_LEN){
        var padding = CIPHER_KEY_LEN-keyBase64.length;
        for(var i=0;i<padding;i++){
            keyBase64+="0";
        }
    }else if(keyBase64.length>CIPHER_KEY_LEN){
        keyBase64 =keyBase64.substring(0, CIPHER_KEY_LEN)
    }

    var key = Buffer.from(keyBase64, 'latin1');
    var iv = Buffer.from(ivBase64,'latin1');
    var encoded_base64_iv= iv.toString('base64');

    var cipher2 = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-128-cbc', key, iv);
    cipher2.write(plainText);
    cipher2.end();

    var cipher_text = cipher2.read();
    var encodedString = cipher_text.toString('base64');

    var final_encrypted_data = encodedString+":"+encoded_base64_iv;

    return final_encrypted_data.toString();
};
```